# What is the function of class ExprRequire in Haxe?

Tags: haxe

I am new to Haxe was trying to compile a *.hx* file. This file uses `ExprRequire`. Is this class deprecated from the latest versions? Everytime, I compile I get class not found `ExprRequire`. I do not also see any file name `ExprRequire.hx` at *\haxe\std\haxe\macro with haxe* versions 2.0.7 and 2.0.8.

If this file is deprecated what class should I be using to replace it. Also if someone could place a simple code that could help me understand the migration from `ExprRequire` to the other class.

-Kshitiz

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding import `haxe.macro.Expr`; ? As far as I known, `ExprRequire` is defined within `haxe.macro.Expr` module. You can read more about modules [here](https://haxe.org/manual/type-system-modules-and-paths.html).

Answer (score 0):

`ExprRequire` is found in `haxe.macro.Expr`. It is actually a replacement for a regular `Expr`, that includes a type for type completion when using the macro. To use that file, all you should have to do is add `import haxe.macro.Expr;` to the top of the file with the other imports.